# After Jquery .html to replace entire div selector on the new div not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Searched and searched.. Cant find reference .. But this must be obvious.

2  select lists

If result if 1st is Australia then keep second list

If not Australia then replace 2nd list by input box.

Works great if you select other than Australia.  But if you then select Australia again nothing happens.

Some debug alerts to see if if is working and a really hinky result in last alert for the value of the div I am looking o replace.

Some assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

PS Sorry about the formatting - had a devil of a time getting the html code into the post

```
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title>Untitled Document</title>
            </head>

            <body>

            <h4>Shipping:</h4>
            <form id="_shipping" class = "shipping-form" method="post" action="payments">

             <Select name ='country' id='country'> 
             <option value='Australia'>Australia </option>
             <option value='USA'>USA </option>
             <option value='Canada'>Canada </option>
             </Select>
             <div id='states' class='states'>
             <select name='state' id='state' class = 'state'>
             <option value='NSW'>NSW </option>
             <option value='ACT'>ACT </option>
             <option value='WA'>WA </option>
             </select>
             </div>

             <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js'> </script>
             <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function() {
                 var bob = $('div#states').html();
                 $('#country').change(function() {
                     var brm = $('#country').val();

                     alert(bob);
                     if(brm === "Australia") {
                         alert('if '+brm);
                         alert('wtf: \r\n' +$('#states').html);

                        $('div#states').empty().html(bob);      //html(bob);


                     } else
                     alert('else '+brm);

                        $('div#states').html("Enter State: <input name = 'state' id = 'state'>");


                 });


                 });

              </script>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that once you set the html to the text input, the select list you had from the beginning is gone. You can either save it for later use, create the select from Javascript, or never actually delete it.

Here's a "create through Javascript" solution:

```
$("#country").change(function() {
    var brm = $(this).val();
    var output = ''; 
    if(brm === "Australia") {
        // Create "states" array
        var states = ["NSW", "ACT", "WA"];
        // Start select tag
        output = '<select name="state" id="state">';
        // Loop through all states and add the options
        for (var i = 0 ; i < states.length ; i++)
            output += '<option value="' + states[i] + '">' + states[i] + '</option>';
        // Close select tag
        output += '</select>';
    } else {
        // Create text input
        output = 'Enter State: <input name="state" id="state">';
    }
    // Set the output
    $('div#states').html(output);
}).trigger("change"); // Trigger the event, so that it runs on page load​​​
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aebWm/

Or if you want to save the select and then reset it:

```
var originalStates =  $('div#states').html();

$("#country").change(function() {
    if($(this).val() === "Australia") {
        $('div#states').html(originalStates)
    } else {
        $('div#states').html('Enter State: <input name="state" id="state">');
    }
});​
```

Comment: I Save the initial select list in variable bob.

Comment: Updated answer which saves the select and resets it. The error in your current code is the lack of `{ }` brackets after `else`

Comment: Oh for the love of ... Thanks so much.  So much for dreamweaver picking up syntax errors. Ok and so far 2 days using Java. :-)

Comment: It's not a syntax error, it just doesn't behave the way you were expecting. And I think you mean Javascript. :)